# Cannot remove a value from a key in dictionary through taking input from user in python

Tags: python, dictionary, user-input

here is the code :

```
dict1 = {"games" : ["football", "cricket"]}
print(dict1)

input1 = input("enter key : ")
input2 = input("enter value : ")

dict1[input1].pop(input2)
```

It gives output as :

```
'games': ['football', 'cricket']}
enter key : games
enter value : football
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/fateo/PycharmProjects/pythonTuts/10Dictionary.py", line 116, in <module>
    dict1[input1].pop(input2)
TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
Process finished with exit code 1
```

it is working fine with append

```
dict1[input1].append(input2)
```

even i tried using for loop :

```
for key, values in dict1.items():
    values.pop(input2)
```

it gives error as :

```
{'games': ['football', 'cricket']}
enter key : games
enter value : football
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/fateo/PycharmProjects/pythonTuts/10Dictionary.py", line 113, in <module>
    values.pop(input2)
TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

Process finished with exit code 1
```

and when i use (int):

```
input2 = int(input("enter value : "))
```

it gives error as

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/fateo/PycharmProjects/pythonTuts/10Dictionary.py", line 110, in <module>
    input2 = int(input("enter value : "))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'football'
```

and i also used del

```
del dict1[input2]
```

it says

```
TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

i do not why it is interpreting it as integer

Comment: `pop` requires index as argument, which is an integer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dont use `pop` try this instead.

```
dict1 = {"games" : ["football", "cricket"]} 

print(dict1)

input1 =input("enter key : ")

input2 = input("enter value : ")

for value in dict1.values():
    if (input2) in value:
        value.remove(input2)
print(dict1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `pop` on list with a string value as argument. The `pop` requires an index of the element which is to be removed.

Because your dictionary has one key, the easiest way you can do is a dictionary-comprehension:

```
{k: [x for x in v if x != input2] for k, v in dict1.items() if k == input1}
```

..which inside your example looks like:

```
dict1 = {"games" : ["football", "cricket"]}
print(dict1)

input1 = input("enter key : ")
input2 = input("enter value : ")

print({k: [x for x in v if x != input2] for k, v in dict1.items() if k == input1})
```

Answer (score 0):

For the pop(), you should give the index, not the key. Even del statement should be giben along with the index. Use remove() instead